# Getting IIS to return 405 on a disallowed verb

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, requestfiltering

A PEN test discovered that a OPTIONS verb returned data from my (ASP.NET 4/MVC 5) server.
Based on a number of sources, in the web.config, I've configured IIS to block this verb using

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <verbs>
                <add verb="OPTIONS" allowed="false"/>
            </verbs>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

This "works" but reponds with a 404 (Not Found). The security team that did the PEN test say this is not sufficient. (And my client, who hired the team really wants me to conform to their requirements).

It's also not what I expect and want: Like said [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)"The request method is known by the server but has been disabled and cannot be used.", thus it should return a 405 (Method Not Allowed).

However, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/configure-request-filtering-in-iis#http-verbs) the current response is by design:
*"When IIS rejects a request based on this feature, the error code logged is 404.6."*. [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404#Substatus_codes) they call it "verb denied".

I don't get this. Why is -in this case suitable (or even standardized?)- response of "405" not given here? And more important: how can I get IIS to respond with a 405 on a disallowed verb/request method?

Comment: "The security team that did the PEN test say this is not sufficient" - what exactly do they find insufficient about it? I agree it's a little strange behaviour from IIS, but it's not exactly invalid.

Comment: Use URL Rewrite module so that you can return a custom 405 response.

Comment: @Xerillio The problem is that this is our best paying customer, who is quite demanding and cautious, so we'll have to do something. The (Barracuda) report gives this a CVSS of 5.0 and states "A request to the site using the OPTIONS method returned successfully, but did not report any allowed HTTP methods. This typically means the
server is treating the OPTIONS request like a GET request, and indicates a misconfiguration. Under certain circumstances, this misconfiguration
could allow attackers to bypass path access restrictions, so it is recommended to disable the OPTIONS method."

Comment: @LexLi that seems to be an extension for IIS. IIS is managed by our ISP, so I don't have access to that (have to request a support ticket for every small configuration change). Isn't there a standard way? URL Rewriter also seems to be 13 year old technology...

Comment: @JHBonarius the text you sent doesn't seem to contradict your first solution (HTTP status 404.6). But regardless, if URL Rewrite doesn't work for you I think your only option is to handle it within the web application itself, e.g. like you've already done. "Old technology" could also be phrased "mature technology" :)

Comment: @Xerillio maybe, but a 404 will lead to our default 404 page "page not found", which triggered this issue. If you know customers, me not changing this now, and they encountering this again in the new PEN test, will lead to them complaining "You don't listen to us". That will harm the relation ship and (especially in these times) that's not good. Customer is king.

Comment: @JHBonarius I'm not trying to convince you to fight the customer, but a dialog about the solution can also strengthen the relationship letting them know you take their decision and money (in case they pay for the hour) serious. Anyway, if URL Rewrite is not a solution I think you should update your question to elaborate what kind of solution you're looking for.

Comment: @Xerillio thanks anyway for your time. I think I can sell my workaround to my team (and the customer will likely be happy).

Comment: IIS URL Rewrite module is rather standard a way (and from Microsoft itself). What you referred to as "URL Rewriter" can be something else. Your solution below is also unnecessarily complex (involving both IIS configuration changes and ASP.NET code changes, and performance overhead). Most ISP should have already installed that IIS module as s many users have been using it for years.

Comment: @LexLi thank you for your time. However, I'm then not fully following you. I would really appreciate it if you can give me some details (maybe in an answer?)

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a workaround using some custom error handling.
My web.config now has

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <verbs>
                <add verb="OPTIONS" allowed="false"/>
            </verbs>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace" >
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1"/>
        <error statusCode="404" subStatusCode="6"
           path="/Error/MethodNotAllowed" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
        <error statusCode="404" path="/Error/NotFound" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
[...etc]
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

And I've added a method to my ErrorController.cs

```cs
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
[...]
    public ActionResult MethodNotAllowed()
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed);
    }
}
```

And this seems to "work". When I use postmaster to request an OPTIONS, I get 405 and when I GET a non existing page, I still get my custom 404 page.